# Get all UID's from IMAP?

Tags: imap

Here is the problem
my gmail account displays that I have 373 emails.
However, when I query the IMAP server with is command
             " SELECT INBOX\r\n"
 it displays that I have  about 968 emails in my inbox instead of 373.

So when I send the following command "UID SEARCH ALL\r\n" to return the UID's of the mails in my inbox, it returns a total of 355 UID's instead of 968 UID's.
Please what am I doing wrong?

What is the correct command to get the number of emails in my inbox? and how do I get all the UID's? I been searching for a good tutorial, the ones I got warent very practical.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, I returned a little bit more, but then I realized that the number of UID's varied with each query I sent, sometimes in the two hundreds another time in the three hundreds.. its not consistent and its never equal ti the number returned by "STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES)\r\n"

Comment: can u please share the output in that format..???